# Array of object reduce typescript error: not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why can't typescript do reduce using below code? Here a [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCmBbADjAvDA2gKBnmA3rviQEQCWAJqQFwykCMpANMSXqdAIZTngS0sRdiJhU6Aci4AjYBLbsAvgF1WJRWvzDRFanVIAmFgrLde-QZm2j84mBMrwAZvJsqFittmXZsoSLAAHuhwSMgAdABO8JQArsDwABSJXMDAsYjMMCAAlOgAfIQKqemI4cixEAAWiSDhZnyQeQD0zQDuVTwSEDBtkeAA5jBV8NEA-L4k0VCxkWAwJRnYGljKOb7+ECAANvDh2yADiYHrQA) as well.

```
const temp = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "stations": [{
            id: 'abc'
        }],
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "stations": [{
            id: 'def'
        }]
    }
   
]

const x = temp.reduce((accum, o) => {
    accum.push(o.stations) //what's wrong here?

    return accum
}, [])
```

Comment: You've given `reduce` `[]` as the starting value. `[]` is always inferred as `never[]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
const x = temp.reduce((accum, o) => { // temp.reduce<never[]>(...)
    accum.push(o.stations) // ! nothing is assignable to never

    return accum
}, []); // inferred as never[]
```

You'll need to either pass the generic to `reduce`, or cast the `[]`:

```
// EITHER one of these will work, choose which one you think "looks" better
const x = temp.reduce<
    typeof temp[number]["stations"][] // here
>((accum, o) => { // temp.reduce<never[]>(...)
    accum.push(o.stations) // ! nothing is assignable to never

    return accum
}, [] as typeof temp[number]["stations"][]); // also works
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCmBbADjAvDA2gWAFAwJgG89CyYAiASwBMKAuSgRgoBpTyCLoBDKK8BAZYS+TuVqMA5DwBGwKR04BfALrsxBZRrKjxlWsIoAmNkvLcofAZGGY9+wpJhSa8AGaLN5NeeVK8VTw8UEhYAA90OCRkADoAJ3gaAFdgeAAeKABPZHgQd2iUTDBkxFl4eNVMS2tBCirVAD4ACmaeYGBS1hgQAEp0RuJzds7EWORkiAALZpBY3n5BfuDvRKhk+LAYEdK8bSxVXoBuFdDoGCyohBQEpNT4Vp3Ebr6Boe8n8cmZuYWbCGWuHMaw2Wyee26mFU2wgcByeQK12QxVK5Uq1T+dQaxzwQA) you will find the two solutions.

---

But may I ask why you are even using reduce here? A simple map could work faster and simpler...

```
const x = temp.map((o) => o.stations);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default empty arrays in Typescript are of type nerver[], So you have to explicitly specify the type

```
const x = temp.reduce((accum, o) => {
    accum.push(o.stations)
    return accum
}, [] as {id: string}[][])
```

Answer (score -1):

In TS empty arrays are by default of type `never[]`. That is what throws the error. You need to properly type it.

Something as simple as this will do:

```
const x = temp.reduce((accum, o) => {
    accum.push(o.stations) //what's wrong here?

    return accum
}, [] as any[])
```

If you want to type it properly just initialize the array as such:

```
const x = temp.reduce((accum, o) => {
    accum.push(o.stations) //what's wrong here?

    return accum
}, [] as { id : string}[][])
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCmBbADjAvDA2gKBnmA3rviQEQCWAJqQFwykCMpANMSXqdAIZTngS0sRdiJhU6Aci4AjYBLbsAvgF1WJRWvzDRFanVIAmFgrLde-QZm2j84mBMrwAZvJsqFittmXZsoSLAAHuhwSMgAdABO8JQArsDwABSJXMDAsYjMMCAAlOgAfIQKqemI4cixEAAWiSDhZnyQeQD0zQDuVTwSEDBtkeAA5jBV8NEA-L4k0VCxkWAwJRnYGljKCz0EYpQwdNCR5GADipjKJzm+-hAgADbw4dcgA4mB50A)

Comment: Please don't suggest using `any` :(